# compile errors after update (ros::console)

Tags: ros, compile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After last update i ran into a few compile errors. Before the weekend everything was working fine, but after the update i can't compile anymore.

What can i do?

This is the output:

```
Linking CXX executable ../bin/ardrone_driver
  CMakeFiles/ardrone_driver.dir/src/ardrone_driver.cpp.o: In function `ARDroneDriver::readCovParams(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::array<double, 9ul>&)':
  /home/jeroen/ROS/packages/ardrone_autonomy/src/ardrone_driver.cpp:313: undefined reference to `ros::console::print(ros::console::FilterBase*, log4cxx::Logger*, ros::console::levels::Level, char const*, int, char const*, char const*, ...)'
  /home/jeroen/ROS/packages/ardrone_autonomy/src/ardrone_driver.cpp:296: undefined reference to `ros::console::print(ros::console::FilterBase*, log4cxx::Logger*, ros::console::levels::Level, char const*, int, char const*, char const*, ...)'
  /home/jeroen/ROS/packages/ardrone_autonomy/src/ardrone_driver.cpp:290: undefined reference to `ros::console::print(ros::console::FilterBase*, log4cxx::Logger*, ros::console::levels::Level, char const*, int, char const*, char const*, ...)'
  /home/jeroen/ROS/packages/ardrone_autonomy/src/ardrone_driver.cpp:307: undefined reference to `ros::console::print(ros::console::FilterBase*, log4cxx::Logger*, ros::console::levels::Level, char const*, int, char const*, char const*, ...)'
  /home/jeroen/ROS/packages/ardrone_autonomy/src/ardrone_driver.cpp:302: undefined reference to `ros::console::print(ros::console::FilterBase*, log4cxx::Logger*, ros::console::levels::Level, char const*, int, char const*, char const*, ...)'
  CMakeFiles/ardrone_driver.dir/src/ardrone_driver.cpp.o:/home/jeroen/ROS/packages/ardrone_autonomy/src/ardrone_driver.cpp:324: more undefined references to `ros::console::print(ros::console::FilterBase*, log4cxx::Logger*, ros::console::levels::Level, char const*, int, char const*, char const*, ...)' follow
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122721/compile-errors-after-update-(ros::console)/) by [jringel77](https://answers.ros.org/users/11271/jringel77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-01-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install -f

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

together with erasing build dirs and rebuilding in your workspace by (in the catkin_ws folder:)

```
rm -r devel
rm -r build
catkin_make
```

(See http://answers.ros.org/question/121266/undefined-symbol/?answer=121291#post-id-121291)

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jringel77](https://answers.ros.org/users/11271/jringel77/) on 2014-01-27**:
thanks solved!

**Comment by [Adnan Munawar](https://answers.ros.org/users/11796/adnan-munawar/) on 2014-02-28**:
Thanks a lot, solved

**Comment by [kargas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4888/kargas/) on 2014-03-24**:
it is not working for me...  any further suggestions?

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-03-24**:
@kargas what kind of errors do you get? undefined ref to what?

**Comment by [kargas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4888/kargas/) on 2014-03-24**:
its kinda different ...

/home/user/hydro_ws/src/openni_camera/src/nodelets/driver.cpp: In member function ‘void openni_camera::DriverNodelet::onInitImpl()’:
/home/user/hydro_ws/src/openni_camera/src/nodelets/driver.cpp:149:3: error: ‘LoggerPtr’ is not a member of ‘log4cxx’
/home/user/hydro_ws/src/openni_camera/src/nodelets/driver.cpp:149:22: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘logger_ccp’
/home/user/hydro_ws/src/openni_camera/src/nodelets/driver.cpp:150:3: error: ‘LoggerPtr’ is not a member of ‘log4cxx’
/home/user/hydro_ws/src/openni_camera/src/nodelets/driver.cpp:150:22: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘logger_cim’
/home/user/hydro_ws/src/openni_camera/src/nodelets/driver.cpp:151:3: error: ‘logger_ccp’ was not declared in this scope
/home/user/hydro_ws/src/openni_camera/src/nodelets/driver.cpp:152:3: error: ‘logger_cim’ was not declared in this scope
/home/user/hydro_ws/src/openni_camera/src/nodelets/driver.cpp:157:3: error: ‘LoggerPtr’ is not a member of ‘log4cxx’
/home/user/hydro_ws/src/openni_

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-03-24**:
Plz create a separate thread and past the the parts of your nodelets/driver.cpp which cause the error (around line 150...)

**Comment by [kargas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4888/kargas/) on 2014-03-24**:
will do Wolf thanks for your concern